# Flickering textures after transform

Tags: javascript, matrix, webgl2

In WebGL2, I have textures (sprites) that move across the screen. With a standard orthographic projection matrix, there is no flickering. When I add transformation (rotation + scaling) to the matrix, the textures starts to flicker and become more "restless".

The transformation is only used for positioning the sprites. After adding the positioning/translation, I perform the opposite transformation so the sprite is drawn in it's original shape.

```
if (transform === true) {
    matrix = m4.scale(matrix, scaleX, scaleY, 1);
    matrix = m4.zRotate(matrix, rotation)
};

matrix = m4.translate(matrix,
    dstX,
    dstY,
    0);

if (transform === true) {
    matrix = m4.zRotate(matrix, -rotation)
    matrix = m4.scale(matrix, scaleX, 1/scaleY, 1);
};
```

In the snippet below, you can toggle transform on and off by clicking at the screen. When transform is on, the flickering is most visible at the top of the sprite.

Is the issue due to sub-pixel rounding errors, because the sprite isn't positioned at a screen pixel position? If so, is there a way to fix it?

```js
let transform = false;
let scaleX = 1;
let scaleY = 0.7;
let rotation = 30 * Math.PI/180;

// Setup WebGL
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const gl = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    
const vs =
    `#version 300 es
    precision highp float;

    in vec2 a_position;
    in vec2 a_texcoord;
            
    uniform mat4 u_matrix;
            
    out vec2 v_texcoord;
            
    void main() {
      gl_Position = u_matrix * vec4(a_position, 0.0, 1.0);

      v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
    }`;
    
const fs =
    `#version 300 es
    precision highp float;
            
    in vec2 v_texcoord;
            
    uniform sampler2D u_texture;
 
    out vec4 outColor;
            
    void main() {
        outColor = texture(u_texture, v_texcoord);
    }`;

// Setup program with shaders
const program = gl.createProgram();

const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vs);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);

const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fs);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);

gl.linkProgram(program);
gl.useProgram(program);

if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    console.error('ERROR compiling vertex shader', gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader))
};
if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    console.error('ERROR compiling fragment shader', gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader))
};

// Setup attributes
const positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_position');
const texcoordLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_texcoord');

// Setup uniforms
const matrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_matrix');
const textureLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_texture");

const vao = gl.createVertexArray();
gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

// Create position buffer
const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
const positionData = new Float32Array([
  0, 0,
  0, 1,
  1, 0,
  1, 0,
  0, 1,
  1, 1
]);

gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    positionLoc, // attribute
    2,           // size
    gl.FLOAT,    // type
    false,       // normalize
    0,           // stride
    0);          // offset

// Create texcoord buffer
const texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
const texcoords = new Float32Array([
    0, 0,
    0, 1,
    1, 0,
    1, 0,
    0, 1,
    1, 1,
]);

gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoords, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLoc);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    texcoordLoc,  // attribute
    2,                          // size
    gl.FLOAT,                   // type
    true,                       // normalize
    0,                          // stride
    0);                         // offset

// Setup texture
let tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]));

gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

let texWidth;
let texHeight;
let img = new Image();
img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    texWidth = img.width;
    texHeight = img.height;
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
});

img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/3VirGxb.png';
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

const draw = function() {
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  
    let matrix = new Float32Array([
        2 / gl.canvas.width, 0, 0, 0,
        0, -2 / gl.canvas.height, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 0,
        -1, 1, 0, 1
    ]);
  
    if (transform === true) {
        matrix = m4.scale(matrix, scaleX, scaleY, 1);
        matrix = m4.zRotate(matrix, rotation)
    };
    
    matrix = m4.translate(matrix,
        dstX,
        dstY,
        0);
  
    if (transform === true) {
        matrix = m4.zRotate(matrix, -rotation)
        matrix = m4.scale(matrix, scaleX, 1/scaleY, 1);
    };
    
    // Scale unit squad from 1x1 to texWidth and texHeight
    matrix = m4.scale(matrix, texWidth, texHeight, 1);
  
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matrixLoc, false, matrix);
    
    let texUnit = 0;
    gl.uniform1i(textureLoc, texUnit);
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + texUnit);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    
    gl.drawArrays(
      gl.TRIANGLES, // method
      0,            // offset
      6,            // number of vertices per instance
      1             // number of instances
);           
}

let dstX = 100;
let dstY = gl.canvas.height/2;
let incX = 1;
let incY = 1;

const update = function() {
    dstX += incX;
    dstY += incY;
    if (dstX < 0) {
      incX = 1;
    }
    if (dstX >= gl.canvas.width - texWidth) {
      incX = -1;
    }
    if (dstY < 0) {
      incY = 1;
    }
    if (dstY >= gl.canvas.height - texHeight) {
      incY = -1;
    }
}

const render = function() {
    update();
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
};

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (transform === true) {
        transform = false;
        document.getElementById('header').textContent = 'Transform off (click to change)';
    } else if (transform === false) {
        transform = true;
        document.getElementById('header').textContent = 'Transform on (click to change)';
        }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: arial;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header">Transform off (click to change)</h1>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src='https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/resources/m4.js'></script>
```

Comment: There is no point in adding tags to the title of the question.

Comment: This looks like sub-pixel weirdness to me, yeah. You could try ensuring that your transform and scale values will only produce pixel-aligned results?

Comment: The rotation needs to stay at 30 degrees. The y scaling doesn't have to be exactly 0.7, so maybe I could adjust the y scaling...

Comment: @Feathercrown Any suggestion on how to ensure pixel-aligned results?

Comment: @Candleout I'm not sure it's possible given that there's a rotation, but I don't have enough experience to say for sure.